# Uploading file webservice, unable to open it

Tags: android, web-services

I'm writting an android app which has to send a picture on a wcf webservice.
My app can contact the web service and give it the picture.
But, size are differents and I can't open the picture on the web service.

EDIT :By changing the webservice part I got the exact same size for both. But, still unable to open it.

Android part (file size 20ko) :

```
File img;
try {
        Log.i("image", "get file");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        Log.i("call", "end build");

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart("data", new FileBody(f));

        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        Log.i("call", "call");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i("call", "After");

    }
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("error cal image", e.toString());
}
```

Edit : 
Webservice (file size 20ko):

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
UriTemplate = "picture")]
public void UploadPicture(Stream image)
{
     var ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.CopyTo(ms);
        var streamBytes = ms.ToArray();
        FileStream f = new FileStream("C:\\appicture.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        f.Write(streamBytes, 0, streamBytes.Length);
        f.Close();
        ms.Close();
        image.Close();


}
```

Comment: byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000]; Is that correct?

Comment: @fonini no it wasn't, Thx. I changed the web service part but still unable to open the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the file in chunks but write only the last chunk:

```
// following line is called once, should be called after each read
fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
```

So try like this:

```
/*...*/
do
{
    bytesRead = image.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytesRead);
} while (bytesRead > 0);

fileToupload.Close();
fileToupload.Dispose();
/*...*/
```